# Can't use wav2vec2-large-xlsr model (Can't load tokenizer )

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

I'm trying to use wav2vec2 (XLSR model) without any success:

```
import transformers
from transformers      import Wav2Vec2ForCTC, Wav2Vec2Processor
import librosa
import torch


wav2vec2_processor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53")
wav2vec2_model = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53")


file_name     = "test.wav"
speech, sr    = librosa.load(file_name, sr=16000)
input_values  = wav2vec2_processor(speech, sampling_rate=16000, return_tensors="pt").input_values

logits        = wav2vec2_model(input_values).logits
```

Error:

```
OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure 'facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53' is the correct path to a directory containing all relevant files for a Wav2Vec2CTCTokenizer tokenizer.
```

How can I use wav2vec2 (XLSR model) ?

Comment: That model was uploaded without a tokenizer and should only be used for fine-tuning.  https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/10696#issuecomment-798786140

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[That particular Wav2Vec model](https://huggingface.co/facebook/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53) only provides the pre-trained representation vectors and doesn't have a fine-tuned CTC/speech recognition model:

> Note that this model should be fine-tuned on a downstream task, like Automatic Speech Recognition.

[jonatasgrosman/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53-english](https://huggingface.co/jonatasgrosman/wav2vec2-large-xlsr-53-english) is a popular fine-tuned CTC model for English based on Wav2Vec2 XLSR, and [models for other languages](https://huggingface.co/models?sort=downloads&search=wav2vec+xlsr) have also been trained.

If you want to use the output of the model anyway (just getting feature vectors from audio), use a `Wav2Vec2FeatureExtractor` instead of `Wav2Vec2Processor`, and `Wav2Vec2Model` instead of `Wav2Vec2ForCTC`.

(A `Wav2Vec2Processor` combines a `FeatureExtractor` and a `Tokenizer` [[docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/wav2vec2#transformers.Wav2Vec2Processor)]. Since tokenization depends on the task the model is fine-tuned for, a speech model that isn't fine-tuned often doesn't have a tokenizer. Credit to [@mmbejani on Github](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/10696#issuecomment-1100525592) for this info.)